# Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js): Error: rails-erb-loader failed with code: 1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, erb

I'd like to use embedded ruby in my javascript. Adding rails-erb-loader, I ended up with the following error:

```
questions.js:50 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js):
Error: rails-erb-loader failed with code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (:3000/Users/xxx/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js:128)
    at ChildProcess.emit (:3000/events.js:315)
    at maybeClose (:3000/internal/child_process.js:1021)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (:3000/internal/child_process.js:286)
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/roadmap.js.erb (questions.js:50)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Any ideas?